# Visual Studio 2012 adding _1 to click event handler

Tags: ide, visual-studio-2012

Visual Studio 2012 is adding _1 to any click event handler I create in XAML

ie: I create a new WPF solution, drop a button, in XAML give button a Name, type 'click' and intellisense brings up  'New Event Handler', I click it, it creates event BUT its named btn_test_click_1

In VS2010 we don't get _1, how can I stop this happening its driving me mad?

**UPDATE**
I can confirm this has been fixed with VS2012 [Update 2](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=38188)

Comment: Are you sure you don't already have a `btn_test_click` method in the code?

Comment: No its new solution with just one button nothing else.

Comment: I have this happening on my end as well. Aesthetically aggravating.

Comment: This is a [known problem](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/759614/silverlight-xaml-designer-new-event-handler-bug) with the XAML editor.  The bug was fixed and will ship in the next *major* VS update, whenever that will be.

Comment: I can confirm this has been fixed with Update 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can confirm this has been fixed with VS2012 [Update 2](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=38188)

Answer (score 1):

It only does that when the IDE see that an existing event handler by the same name has been created.  Make sure you delete the event handle info from the code file then go to the aspx file and remove any event handle connections on the control.  Then save the file.

Comment: Its a new solution with just one button, there is no existing handler. VS2010 doesn't do it just 2012.

Comment: @Eugene, I can confirm that the problem really exist in VS 2012, even when you do not have an existing event handler with the same name.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the `_1` manually and as you say you only have one event handler, so there shouldn't be any other code logic that would run on your event.

Comment: You miss my point, I know I can delete it, its  quite annoying. Its a bug so will have to wait till fixed.